# How come the builtin del does not call the listed internal class's __del__() as well?

Tags: python, list

Say we have a class `Foo`

```
class Foo:
    def __del__(self):
        # do some kind of deleting

    def run(self):
        # run something
```

And foo has been added to a list. Its methods will be used later in the program.

```
l = [Foo()]
```

Foo is now inside a list.
If I wanted to use the method `run` I simply call `l` along with its index and method

```
l[0].run()
```

Now if I want to run the `__del__` method. I could call `Foo`'s method `__del__`

```
l[0].__del__()
```

---

My question is:

why isn't `del l[0]` not the same as `l[0].__del__()`

---

Edit:

After messing around a little further, I've found that `list[0].__del__()` and  `del list[0]` do produce the same results, however calling `__del__` does not remove the item in the list, `del` does however

```
class Foo:

    def __del__(self):
        print("Deleting")

list = [Foo()]

print(list)
list[0].__del__()
print(list)
del list[0]
print(list)
```

---

```
>
[<Foo object at 0x7f4ad04d97f0>]
Deleting
[<Foo object at 0x7f4ad04d97f0>]
Deleting
[]
>
```

Comment: *How come I can't simply do something like this to run Foo's method?* To run *what* method?

Comment: I was using `l[0].run()` as a comparison of running `l[0].__del__()`

Comment: And `del` doesn't exist to call `__del__`. `__del__` is a hook method *when the object is removed from memory*. `del` removes a reference to an object, and only when the reference count drops to 0 will the object be removed from memory.

Comment: So does that mean that I should just rename the function `__del__`

Comment: You would not normally call `__del__()` directly, that won't delete the object. That's simply calling the hook method in a different context. Your object still is referenced, still exists in memory.

Comment: I am skeptical you even need to implement `__del__()`, what, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: @tisaconundrum: only give your class a `__del__` method if you need to clean up resources when your object is deallocated. If you are not using it for that purpose, then you are using it incorrectly and should probably not use that name, no.

Comment: Also, I think `del l[0]` calls `l.__delitem__(0)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: yes, and if that removes the last reference to the `Foo` instance, then the `__del__()` method is called *too*.